# Javascript function output | Constructor typeof

Tags: javascript, constructor, typeof

could someone please explain why this function is returning the value as true?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Array Object</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = isArray(fruits);

function isArray(myArray) {
return myArray.constructor === Array;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward. I don't understand why you would expect it to be anything other than true. What don't you understand about it? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: I have edited the question with the one I wanted to ask. can you please explain rather than asking me?

Comment: I still don't understand why you are confused. What would you expect the constructor of an array be anything other than `Array`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript constructors. I am not sure what myArray.constructor === Array; implies to?

Comment: in javascript, there is no class concepts. so the constructor here is not what you expect as in other programming languages. if you use a function to create an object, the function becomes constructor. in this case constructor is Array.

Comment: Usual arrays inherit the [`Array.prototype.constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Properties), which refers to `Array`.

Comment: both have type "function" but how they are equal in the value? as === needs the equal value and equal type. Thanks

Comment: They are equal in value because they are the same object. Why wouldn't an array have the Array constructor function as its constructor?

Comment: They are not the same object lol, they are the same constructor functions `Array() { [native code] }`

Comment: @Auine — Constructor functions are functions. Functions are objects. If they are the same constructor function then they are the same object.

Comment: @Quentin functions aren't objects
`typeof Array === "function"`, they are `function object` They are equal by reference to the same function, not object.

Comment: @Auine — Functions are objects. https://jsbin.com/femuwohasi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Quentin Functions are `function object`, they are special in JS and can return values etc.

Comment: @Auine — I drive a Leon. It is a car. It is a vehicle. The fact it is a car does not stop it being a vehicle. The fact `Array` is a function does not stop it also being an object. Functions are a subset of object, not a completely seperate data type.

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because arrays are constructed with the `Array` constructor function, even if you use array literal syntax.

Comment: and can u explain ur jsbin example also.

Comment: @rohitwtbs — They refute statements made in incorrect answers.

Comment: sorry, i did not get it. i want to what exactly === operator is checking in different scenarios.

Comment: @rohitwtbs — It checks if two values are the same value (in every scenario).

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.constructor` is equal to `Array` because `.constructor` property has a reference to the same value - `Array`. Why? Because it was constructed by constructor function `Array`. `Array === Array` is true

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray.constructor === Array;
```

Both have type '***function***' so it will always turn out to be ***true***.

lets take this code.

```
let a=2;
console.log(a === Array);
```

this will log ***false*** because here we compare a ***number type*** with ***function type.***

Comment: agreed both have type "function" but how they are equal in the value? as === needs the equal value and equal type. Thanks